# Oracle insert huge amount of data via SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have couple of ORACLE tables that I need to use to load a 3rd table. The total number of rows to load comes around 30 million. My `Insert` SQL query is a `INSERT-INTO-<TABLE>-SELECT`.

My query hangs (waited for 30 mins before killing the session). But when I used `ROWNUM` in the `SELECT` query with the `ROWNUM` value equal to the total number of result rows, the `INSERT` query ran in 43 seconds.

And, both the results are consistent.

I am completely lost here. Can anyone please throw their expert opinion on why the INSERT query without ROWNUM hangs and the INSERT query with ROWNUM runs much faster ?

**Details :**

- TABLE - A : has a total of 50,000,000  rows; Primary key on column1 and 12 other indexes including one on column2
- TABLE - B : has a total of 200,000 rows; Index present in COLUMN1 (Relation with TABLE-A is one to many)
- TABLE - C : Output table

**Original INSERT query:**

```
INSERT INTO C 
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM A WHERE COLUMN2 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM B);

Data Types involved in the above query are NUMBER.
```

**INSERT query with ROWNUM :**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM A
WHERE COLUMN2 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM B); -- No issues with this query

INSERT INTO C 
    SELECT COLUMN1 FROM A
    WHERE COLUMN2 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM B) AND ROWNUM <=30,000,000; -- result from the above select query
```

[image: Explain Plan of the query with rownum]

[image: Explain Plan of the query without rownum]

Comment: Did you check the execution plan for each of your select queries?

Comment: That doesn't answer your question, but I suspect you could significantly speed this up if you rewrote the query to use an `INNER JOIN` (`INSERT INTO C SELECT A.COLUMN1 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN2;`) and put an index on `COLUMN2` in `A` (`CREATE INDEX A_COLUMN2 ON A (COLUMN2);`).

Comment: Thanks @Shrek & &sticky bit for your comments.

Comment: @Shrek, added the explain plans for both the queries.

Comment: Are you sure the first insert wasn't just blocked by some other uncommitted activity? Is this repeatable, within a single session?

Comment: How many indexes on the table C? Before insert in table C, drop all indexes on the table C and create indexes after insert.